# Simple way to ping node js app and automatically restart pm2 proccess

Tags: node.js, linux, monitoring, pm2

We have linux ubuntu 20 server with pm2 and nginx. And two node js app running via pm2. Is there any simple way to monitor some app endpoint and automatically restart pm2 app if this endpoint is not responding? I know about PM2 monitor - but it costs 40 USD for month. Maybe there is another way to configure it?

Comment: Just asking. Shouldn't you fix the endpoint for not responding?

Comment: I mean that I need something like pingrobot. So we have the node app running on pm2 and we need to ping some test endpoint. If endpoint isn’t responding then we need automatically restart of the node app